# How do I duplicate an armature and rig?

Tags: rigging

I have an armature/mesh in my scene. I want to duplicate this rig multiple times so I can have multiple instances of the same character. Problem is that all the armatures behave to their meshes, but only the original driver panel (floating above the character's head) controls all the other characters. This is very confusing for me and I would appreciate any help you could give.

This rig is appended to my scene (not linked) and I have not set any keyframes.

I know very little about rigs, so extra detail is appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. a .blend file would be helpful. use [pasteall](http://pasteall.org/)

Comment: What rig do you use downloaded somewhere, rigify or mhx?

Comment: I'm using a Rig downloaded from online. (http://rymdnisse.net/downloads/minecraft-blender-rig.html) It's the Cycles version. Download it/extract it and it's the rig contained in Minecraft_Character_Rig.blend. When I select it and duplicate it, the bones inside the character work for the new character, but only the control panels above the original characters head will work (It also controls every single duplicate you've made). The new panel for the duplicated character does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution:** You have to append the rig multiple times instead of duplicating it. Duplicating will basically make another instance, while appending again will make an entirely new armature/mesh in the .blend file.

Comment: Could you please make your answer more substantial?

Comment: That's it really, there's nothing more to say. You just append the rig over again and you're ready to go. There's a different between a short concise answer and a whole lot of fluff.